# Can't power DM542 stepper motor driver with "Drok" power supply vs. Keysight at the same voltage

Tags: power-supply, stepper-driver

I am trying to use a Drok power supply with a DM542.

I am using 15V to to drive the DM542. For the Keysight U8031A, it works (the green light turns on.) For the Drok, I bought the 10A version, and whenever the voltage increases to over roughly 12V, **both** green light and red light (constant, no blinking) turn on.

I think it is a current problem. For the Drok it said output of 0-36V, 10A. For Keysight it said 0-30V, 6A /  5V, 3A.

I am pretty new to this and have no idea what could go wrong. Could someone shed some light on this?

[Drok 10A](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08GFQZFC1)

Comment: The "Drok" does not look like a particularly high quality supply. What does the its manual say about the green and red light turning on? Did you read the notice about inductive loads on the product's website? **Note that the DM542 manual (to which you did not provide a link) recommends a 20V-45V supply voltage and 15V might be too low.**

Comment: Show link to motor

Comment: Hey! Thank you for replying. I did try with 20V, but what I meant is whenever I try to even increase voltage above 12V with "Drok," the motor driver red light turns on and won't work. So 20V won't work either. 

I actually didn't even connect the motor to the motor driver (just power supply and driver), but here is the link for Nema 17, 1:5 Geared:  https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00QA5WSDG/ref=vp_d_ac_sub_sp_pd?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B00QA5WSDG&pd_rd_w=pME0z&pf_rd_p=3aa6d111-6089-48e3-8854-0ce754a566d2&pf_rd_r=YY1W6NFTHWQX5DF2AQ24&pd_rd_r=8f01faca-713a-461b-81be-a481a89c1382&pd_rd_wg=LdtNR

Answer (score 1):

What matters is the DCR of both motor coils that affects the start current, I=V/DCR for each coil and the supply's response to a transient load.  The motor  impedance rises rapidly with velocity as BEMF reduces current between positions. Using conservative current-limiting settings means higher voltage settings is not going to help, rather makes it worse if it cannot regulate the current limits.

---

You cannot use 15V if it is demanding charge currents beyond the settings for a step load the undershoot causes the DC OK comparators inside to say not OK and turn on the RED LED.

In your case, the surge current is probably causing overshoot and undershoot and shutting down for false DC OK internally on each step. Then OK when stopped.  Thus the red light is turning on and flashing.

**This is a sign of poor step load response in a power supply design.(or very sloppy wiring and system setup)**

Adding a dummy preload might help with a light bulb on the power supply as a "Bandaid" so that the current ratios are reduced. Or perhaps very low ESR CAPs added. But it can also make it worse if the supply is low design quality with too much stored energy vs demand energy with inadequate compensation.

[image]

[image]

https://kitaez-cnc.com/f/dm542.pdf

### 2nd opinion

**From the [Drok Website](https://www.droking.com/480W-AC-Power-Supply-Switching-AC110-220V-to-DC0-48V-10A-Led-Display-Adjustable-Voltage-Regulator-DC-12V-24V-Power-Adapter-Driver) > Reviews > Page 13**

> Very Well Designed and is Regulated 5.0stars K.R. Grass Valley 07/02/2018

> I'm an electronics engineer and have disassembled the DROCK, first to clear up t**he usual all over the map reviews**, the supply is regulated and quite well, the filtering is excellent as well as the design, it's based on well-proven designs and functions perfectly, the meter is also very accurate, a little small, but serves the purpose.

> If your using this power supply for a CNC project driving your stepper motors ***banding the output within a safe range is the correct way***, incase of failure it may save your stepper drives

> To change the output voltage using the extra 5K control:
> for a 0-20V output add a 4.7K resistor in series with yellow wire, for a 20-50V output add a 4.7K resistor in series with the red wire
> for a 12-25V output add a 4.7K resistor to both the red and yellow wires
> Mine for a deeper mod to get a 20-48V output I used the 10K control and added a 330-ohm resistor in series with the yellow wire and a 33K
> the resistor in series with the red wire, the wire colors are referenced to the wire colors on the controls

### My Comments

Evaluating a power supply design properly is almost as hard as designing it. You have to know all the design specifications intimately and test each with margin to know how well it was designed using 10 samples to fit the expected population. You also must have equivalent design skills to know where to how to test for margin with non-destructive tests within the spec.  If the design and customer specs are thin , your confidence should be suspicious. Obviously Amazon, Ebay or Alibaba is not going to post these specifications or guarantees by the OEM. Nor is it the most reliable place to go shopping for quality, but sometime you get lucky. In order to find test failures in any design, you must have detailed specifications that include the range of dynamic load and voltage errors you expect for your application.

Critical Specs such as % step load regulation vs overshoot and ripple voltage & spectrum, common-mode and differential noise and Hipot margin with a PE grounded secondary.  Design Specs take about 10 to 30 pages, not one paragraph with no conditions. If you can't get these, then at a minimum, a 5-page spec. *[like a transistor specification.](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/pzt3904-d.pdf)*   I was trained to perform Design Verification/Validation Testing DVT on disk drives and power supplies as a former employee of a large US Corp., but I already had 10 yrs R&D experience in relevant technology. Every spec was tested and validated with margin. The better suppliers like Lambda, Shindengen, and Fujitsu had no faults, while others did, like PowerOne. Even Hammond and Brown had intermittent weaknesses that required small changes in crosstalk step-load regulation errors.

My suspicion is that this power supply was tested with linear loads and ramped over the expected range, it would perform well. It has all the external quality indicators of a Meanwell clone with additional features like a DVM and a remote control port. Some users commented the pot was hard to set to the desired voltage. That's a sensitivity issue.  This user describes how to reduce that control range, but that has nothing to do with feedback compensation or stepper dynamic load response with unknown reactive energy stored in the driver Caps and the motor inductance and interia.  This is why **he suggests limiting the current or choosing a lower strap level**. This will of course reduce the acceleration and maximum speed/torque.

### recommendations

A deeper analysis of the output V-I waveform is necessary to explain why the RED LED flickers from voltage errors. I might use a 50 mV shunt resistor on the ground to measure current or use a 1MHz current probe then measure ripple with an AC coupled 50 Ohm load on a DSO with coax or a cap to 450:50 ohm divider.  I would only use twisted-pair wiring everywhere to avoid crosstalk and driver resonance during PWM dead-time and use an RF cap from DC ground to PE ground to suppress the high CM noise expected.

Add a dummy preload resistance like an automobile 35W headlamp bulb rated for 14.5V . with socket and lead wires. See if the performance changes. Check the driver's current limit settings and try different settings.  Beef up the wiring with twisted pairs. Post the motor specs, Report the motor DCR coil resistance and show photographs of the system. Measure what you can with the tools you have like a DMM AC voltage on a 50mV/5A= 10m or a 50 milliohm shunt resistor on 0V return to supply.

I expect the user to perform some tests and update his question with test results test method and motor specs with driver settings and command acceleration rates.

**If you do not have the tools to follow all my suggestions, then you need a better power supply.**